# Add index column for txt file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Given a `sample.txt` file as follows:

```
2860    3117
318 1610    1776    1865    2283    2507    3076    3108    3182    3357    3675    4040
164 413 1448    1650    3119    3238
164 172 712 849 872 983 1616    1826    1973    2118    2291    2819    2978    3238    3365
95  97  143 196 317 374 375 482 526 544 615 753 784 850 852 1023    1060    1078    1103    1106    1110    1118    1135    1178    1189    1198    1255    1277    1312    1332    1348    1368    1425    1428    1589    1616    1694    1726    1749    1763    1800    1894    1907    2082    2168    2254    2296    2322    2356    2468    2524    2578    2592    2672    2728    2737    2792    2978    3119    3164    3231    3289    3357    3375    3437    3474    3477    3523    3583    3618    3628    3638    3857    3965
857 1436    1739    3278    3700    3754    3788    3976
```

How could I add line index starting from `0` in the beginning of each line using Python?

```
0 2860  3117
1 318   1610    1776    1865    2283    2507    3076    3108    3182    3357    3675    4040
2 164   413 1448    1650    3119    3238
3 164   172 712 849 872 983 1616    1826    1973    2118    2291    2819    2978    3238    3365
4 95    97  143 196 317 374 375 482 526 544 615 753 784 850 852 1023    1060    1078    1103    1106    1110    1118    1135    1178    1189    1198    1255    1277    1312    1332    1348    1368    1425    1428    1589    1616    1694    1726    1749    1763    1800    1894    1907    2082    2168    2254    2296    2322    2356    2468    2524    2578    2592    2672    2728    2737    2792    2978    3119    3164    3231    3289    3357    3375    3437    3474    3477    3523    3583    3618    3628    3638    3857    3965
5 857   1436    1739    3278    3700    3754    3788    3976
```

Thanks.

To read the txt file, I use:

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
with open('sample.txt') as infile, open('sample_.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for idx, line in enumerate(infile):
        outfile.write(f'{idx} {line}')
# Rename or replace
# shutil.move('sample_.txt, 'sample.txt')
```